# 8085 assembly question. Why flag stacks named d0-d7?

Tags: terminology, naming, assembly

I'm trying to make my C programming exciting by learning assembly programming.

I've encountered an image of flag registers in 8085 assembly programming. In that image blocks are named from d0-d7(numerals in subscript). Why are they named 'd'? Is this arbitrarily chosen? There is another register with the name 'D', are both same or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image you saw is like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1x9F.jpg), `D0`-`D7` imply bit positions in the status register, called `F` (for flags) when part of the `AF` register pair.  The Ds are misleading because they imply some (nonexistent) relationship to the `D` register or the data pins (which are multiplexed with the address lines and are actually called `AD0`-`AD7`).

Describing bit positions for the status flags doesn't mean much of anything for most people because the only instructions that operate on `F` deal with a single bit at a time (conditional jumps, conditional subroutine calls and the instructions that set and clear the carry flag).  The only way to operate on the flags as a whole would be to transfer them to or from another register by way of the stack.

Comment: Yes, that's how the image looked. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is difference

`d0-d7` are 8 bit data bus and 
 `D` is one of the register in 8085

Answer (score 0):

In 8086 assembly that I learnt in Uni, D stood for data. There were four main register groups, AX, BX, CX, DX. Accumulator, Base, Count, and Data. And I suspect it didn't hurt that they were ABCD.

Comment: The register structure on the 8086 was not the same as the 8085.